# python mysql Warning: Data truncated for column 'col1' at row 1 curs.execute(query)

Tags: mysql

```
query = "INSERT INTO temperatur(datum, uhrzeit, ort, messwert) VALUES(CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), 'ort', messwert)";
curs.execute(query)
```

drops out this->

```
Warning: Data truncated for column 'uhrzeit' at row 1 curs.execute(query)
Warning: Data truncated for column 'ort' at row 1 curs.execute(query)
```

how to format CURRENT_DATE() and NOW() ?
ort is a string and messwert a float

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| datum    | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uhrzeit  | time    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ort      | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| messwert | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: What is the schema for this table? Edit your question to include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE temperatur`. "String" isn't a MySQL column type, but `VARCHAR` is.

Comment: Also if `messwert` is a float then you should insert a float value.

Comment: added the structure

Comment: `ort` cannot possibly contain more than one letter, so that's why your insert fails.